# QTreeWidget border radius toggles visibility during scrolling when set alternating row colors

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qtreewidget

I am trying to design a `QTreeWidget` with border-radius. The problem sets in when I assign alternate row colors to it. When I don't, it works fine, and the border-radius around the widget is always visible during scrolling. However, when I scroll with the alternate row colors set, during even numbered rows being at the top and bottom, the border-radius remains as expected, while during odd numbered ones, they are eclipsed, with the look and feel of a widget with no border-radius. Here's what it looks like when the grey colored rows are at the top and bottom:

[image]

And after you scroll one unit, or odd number of units, so that the white colored rows are at the ends, this is what it looks like:

[image]

How do I fix this? And in Windows, because the scrollbars are differently styled, the right side will always have the border radius eclipsed due to the scroll pane. Is there a way to make it behave just like the Mac scrollbar?

My style sheet is pretty minimal:

```
#myTreeWidget {background-color: #C2C7CB; border-radius: 8px; }
```

I set the width of the rows through a delegate:

```
class ItemDelegate : public QItemDelegate
{
public:
  ItemDelegate()
  {}
  QSize sizeHint ( const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index ) const
  {
    return QSize(240,25);
  }
};

ItemDelegate *delegate = new ItemDelegate();

myTreeWidget = new QTreeWidget(this);
myTreeWidget->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("myTreeWidget"));
myTreeWidget->setAttribute(Qt::WA_MacShowFocusRect,false);
myTreeWidget->setGeometry(QRect(20, 10, 240, 375));
myTreeWidget->headerItem()->setHidden(true);
myTreeWidget->setItemDelegate(delegate);
myTreeWidget->setAlternatingRowColors(true);
```

I just observed a weird thing. If I remove the background color from the widget, the border radius completely disappears. Not visible under any circumstance!

Comment: I can't reproduce this. What is your version of OS X and Qt? It's supposed to work, so if some OS X + Qt combination doesn't support it, it's a bug in Qt and you can't do anything about it other than fixing Qt, I think.

Comment: Qt 5.3 32 bit, OS X 10.10 Yosemite. If you hover over the scrollbar, the scrollbar will thicken, which is normal OS X behavior. Then you will see this thing..

Comment: OK, this is a Qt bug then and you should report it. Make sure to search for bug reports first, it could be already reported.

Comment: Okay, will do then. In the meantime, I have modified my problem to something different, but intractable still, so will update soon.